# C# add new row to bound datagridview using relations

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

How can I add a new row in a `DataGridView` when using relations?

When the `DataGridView` is bound to a `DataTable`, I can add a row, but when I`m using relations, nothing happens, the row won't add to the`DataGridView`.

Comment: after updating the binding if you donot see row added then you need to refresh Datagridview

Comment: datagridview.update(); and datagridview.refresh(); doest not work

Comment: can you show us the code perhaps we could see it and help you out

Comment: DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("UserName",typeof(string));

            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = 1;
            dr["UserName"] = "maxWhite";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Answer (score 0):

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("UserName",typeof(string));

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = 1;
        dr["UserName"] = "maxWhite";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

before this i use relations, ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation .......... 
and after this i can`t add row
            dataGridView3.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dataGridView3.DataMember = "relation_name";

because i must use data binding to filter out my result, eg. i click on parent datagrid 1 and in datagrid 2 i see child rows

e.g. i click in parent grid Ford in child grid shows all Ford models, then on Mazda and so on, and i can`t add row to child grid, because i have relation, when i delete relation all i fine.

Comment: datagridview1.Items .. there is no function Items in datagrid